# dayjs diff between two date in day and hours

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, dayjs

I wanna calculate the difference between the two dates with dayjs library. it works nice but I need to something different a little bit. For example:

```
`${dayjs(item).diff(now, 'day') day}`
```

this function returns '20 days' or whatever. but there are hours that are not calculated inside 'item'. I mean it should be like '20 days 9 hours'.

How can I do this with dayjs?

Thanks for any helps

Comment: Get the difference in seconds, then convert those to the desired format (days/hours)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between two time using dayjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60226101/difference-between-two-time-using-dayjs)

Comment: Get the difference in hours and then convert it into days and hours.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. Get the difference in hours
2. Divide (and round) hours by 24 to get the days
3. Get the remainder, those are the left hours

```js
const date1 = dayjs('2021-03-13');
const date2 = dayjs();

let hours = date2.diff(date1, 'hours');
const days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
hours = hours - (days * 24);

console.log('Days: ', days);
console.log('Hours: ', hours);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.21/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```

---

The same logic could be done using seconds, then apply a function to convert those seconds into days/hours/minuts: [Convert seconds to HH-MM-SS with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322732/convert-seconds-to-hh-mm-ss-with-javascript)

Comment: Not all days are 24 hours long where daylight saving is in use, so this method is not always accurate. There are a huge number of questions and answers already on the [difference between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+difference+between+two+dates).

Answer (score 7):

You can obtain the number of days with decimals (adding `true` as second parameter to `diff` and work with it:

```js
const date1 = dayjs('2021-03-13');
const date2 = dayjs();
const diff = date2.diff(date1,'day',true);
console.log("obtained", diff);
const days = Math.floor(diff);
const hours = Math.floor((diff - days) * 24);
console.log(`${days} days, ${hours} hours`);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.21/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`${dayjs(item).diff(now, '`hour`') day}` instead of `${dayjs(item).diff(now, '`day`') day}`

That second parameter is the unit of measurement to use and you set it to day