# Tried everything, the cookies don't set but I have the right headers, cors, things, fetch parameter, etc

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, axios, cors

This has been like 4 days I try to fix this issue, I fixed this issue in http but in https it doesn't work (the server and the website are in https)

For the server I use NodeJS, Express, here is the middleware code:
server/api/index.ts

```
export default function APIHandler(app: e.Express) {
  app.use(
    cookieSession({
      secret: randomUUID(),
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: true,
      httpOnly: true,
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + 2592000000),
    })
  );

  app.enable("trust proxy");

  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: "https://persona-db.vercel.app",
      preflightContinue: true,
      credentials: true,
      allowedHeaders:
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Set-Cookie",
    })
  );

  // app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  //   res.header("Set-Cookie", "true");

  //   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.headers.origin); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  //   res.header(
  //     "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
  //     ""
  //   );
  //   res.header(
  //     "Access-Control-Request-Headers",
  //     "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  //   );

  //   res.header(
  //     "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
  //     "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE"
  //   );
  //   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

  //   next();
  // });

  app.use("/files", e.static(path.join(__dirname, "files")));

  let singlerMulter = multer({ dest: "./api/files" }).single("file");

  app.use(singlerMulter);
  app.use(e.json());
  app.use(e.urlencoded());
  app.use(cookieParser());

  app.use(logger);

  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello World");
  });

  app.use("/characters", charactersRoute);
  app.use("/users", usersRoute);
}
```

Here is how I set a cookie server-side (POST /users/login):

```
route.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  let { username, password } = req.body;

  if (!username || !password)
    return res
      .status(500)
      .json({ message: "Username or password not provided" });

  let u = await collection.findOne({ username });

  if (!u || !compareSync(password, u.password))
    return res
      .status(404)
      .json({ message: "Cannot find account with username and password" });

  if (u.suspendedAt) {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66639760/dayjs-diff-between-two-date-in-day-and-hours Answer

    const date1 = dayjs(u.suspendedAt);
    const date2 = dayjs();

    let hours = date2.diff(date1, "hours");
    const days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
    hours = hours - days * 24;

    res.status(403).json({
      message: `account suspended, ask the support to recover within ${days} days and ${hours} hours.`,
    });

    return;
  }

  res.cookie("token", u.token); // Here is it, and I also tried adding secure/httpOnly params

  res.json({ message: "Logged in", token: u.token });
});
```

Client-side, here is my axios request:
/login/+page.svelte

```
try {
    let result = await axios.post(`${root}/users/login`,{ username: usernameInput.value,password: passwordInput.value},{ withCredentials: true });

    writeSuccess(result.data.message);

    window.location.href = '/';
    } catch (e) {
        writeError(e.response.data.message);
        console.log(e);
    }
```

My website is hosted on Vercel, so it is https, and my server is hosted on a nodejs service, but with cloudflare and a old domain name, it is now not an IP so it's https both the server and client

I really did everything, and still the cookies on the login and register aren't set, this is so annoying, tried everything, the solutions on stackoverflow, nothing worked. So please help me.
If there is Nginx configurations to add server side, I will ask my founder to set it, thank you.

Thanks for your help